# The rep function calculating mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, visualization

This is my sample data:

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x2 <- c(6, 7, 4, 5, 7)
x3 <- c(4, 5, 3, 7, 1)
x4 <- c(3, 5, 6, 4, 2)
x5 <- c(1, 3, 4, 4, 2)
x6 <- c(4, 5, 4, 3, 5)

df <- data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3, x4 = x4, x5 = x5, x6 = x6)


df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    var1_mean = mean(c(x1, x2, x3)),
    var2_mean = mean(c(x4, x5, x6))
  )
```

What I want, is a boxplot that shows the mean of `var1_mean` , including standard deviation, in the first box, and the same thing for `var2_mean` in the other box. The code below seems to do the job, but I'm not sure because I don't understand this `rep` function. Could you please clarify this to me? I've been told, that this object `c(rep("var1_mean", nrow(df)), rep("var2_mean", nrow(df)))` is a vector, with two strings, `var1_means` and `var2_means`, each repeated a number of times equal to the number of rows in df. Does this mean, that it calculates the means and standard deviations of the aforementioned variables?

```
plot_df <- data.frame(
  Variable = c(rep("var1_mean", nrow(df)), rep("var2_mean", nrow(df))),
  Value = c(df$var1_mean, df$var2_mean)
)

ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Mean Value") +
  ggtitle("Box Plot of var1_mean and var2_mean") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you want the standard deviations to be shown in the plot? Standard deviations are not calculated anywhere in your code.  As it is your box plots do show the distributions of the row-wise means you want.  `rep` simply repeats its first argument.  You can explore its behaviour by trying eg `rep("Hello!",10)` and by examining the contents of the `plot_df` frame you created.

Comment: '*Does this mean, that it calculates the means and standard deviations of the aforementioned variables?'*- they're strings, why would adding them to a dataframe calculate that? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no calculation in `rep()`.
`ggplot()` input data is generally in long format, where in this case there should be a column with variable names and another with values; but in `df` columns `var1_mean` & `var2_mean` form a wide format subset:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6 var1_mean var2_mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1     6     4     3     1     4      3.67      2.67
#> 2     2     7     5     5     3     5      4.67      4.33
#> 3     3     4     3     6     4     4      3.33      4.67
#> 4     4     5     7     4     4     3      5.33      3.67
#> 5     5     7     1     2     2     5      4.33      3
```

Your provided code introduces a somewhat uncommon approach for wide to long transformation. `rep()` just repeats (string) objects, values in another col are copied as-is from `var1_mean` & `var2_mean` columns of `df` tibble (don't mind different formatting and apparent rounding, underlying values are still the same):

```
data.frame(
  Variable = c(rep("var1_mean", nrow(df)), rep("var2_mean", nrow(df))),
  Value = c(df$var1_mean, df$var2_mean)
)
#>     Variable    Value
#> 1  var1_mean 3.666667
#> 2  var1_mean 4.666667
#> 3  var1_mean 3.333333
#> 4  var1_mean 5.333333
#> 5  var1_mean 4.333333
#> 6  var2_mean 2.666667
#> 7  var2_mean 4.333333
#> 8  var2_mean 4.666667
#> 9  var2_mean 3.666667
#> 10 var2_mean 3.000000
```

As there already are bits of Tidyverse in provided code, a common way to approach this to get basically identical result would be `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  select(var1_mean, var2_mean) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    Variable  Value
#>    <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 var1_mean  3.67
#>  2 var2_mean  2.67
#>  3 var1_mean  4.67
#>  4 var2_mean  4.33
#>  5 var1_mean  3.33
#>  6 var2_mean  4.67
#>  7 var1_mean  5.33
#>  8 var2_mean  3.67
#>  9 var1_mean  4.33
#> 10 var2_mean  3
```